# How to measure table row height in pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using Javascript, how to get table row height in actual pixels? In the example, I would like to get measurement from top of green border to the top of the next green border.

Using jQuery .height(), outerHeight(), .offsetHeight and .clientHeight does not return correct answer (it's 44px). (see http://jsfiddle.net/kaG7g/8/ )

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr><td>this a table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>this is a contents</td></tr>
    <tr id="tableElement"><td>of element</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
    height:20px;
    border-top:10px solid green;
    border-bottom:10px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: `20px (height)+ 10px+10px(border) +2px+2px (margin)`

Comment: how to do it using javascript?

Comment: Change box model to border-box?

Comment: did you try `.innerHeight()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/kaG7g/12/)

```
console.log( $('td').css('border-top').split('p')[0] );
console.log( $('td').css('border-bottom').split('p')[0] );
console.log( $('td').height() );
```

Comment: the first two values are empty string

Answer (score 0):

Use [This](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

```
var height = $('#table').height();
```

Comment: that would be the entire #table

Comment: use this and subtract border size.

Comment: how to to get measurement from top of green border to the top of the next green border? using javascript

Comment: **as like that**  :- var total =$('td').height();  var bt =$('td').css("border-top"); var bb =$('td').css("border-bottom"); bt=parseInt(bt);  bb=parseInt(bb);      
    alert(total);
    alert(bt);
    alert(bb);

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code..

```
$("#table tr").height()
```

Comment: that is 42px. the answer should be 44px.